# Exact change in python via recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm asked to write a recursive function in python:

```
def exact_change( target_amount, L ):
```

where the input target_amount is a single non-negative integer value and the input L is a list of positive integer values. Then, exact_change should return either True or False: it should return True if it’s possible to create target_amount by adding up some-or-all of the values in L. It should return False if it’s not possible to create target_amount by adding up some-or-all of the values in L.

For example, L could represent the coins you have in your pocket and target_amount could represent the price of an item – in this case, exact_change would tell you whether or not you can pay for the item exactly.

```
exact_change( 42, [25, 1, 25, 10, 5, 1] )

True

exact_change( 42, [25, 1, 25, 10, 5] )

False
```

I've looked up some of the 'change-making problem' solutions, but I can't really figure out how to program this function.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. I have no clue how to start...

Comment: Maybe note that `exact_change(42, [25, 1, 25, 10, 5, 1])` is the same than `exact_change(32, [25, 1, 25, 5, 1])`…

Comment: But if I subtract the first character of the list, how would it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sorting L in reverse we try to use up the biggest coins first. This should take care about situations mentioned by @MathiasEttinger.
For sure re-sorting the already sorted L at each recursive call is redundant, but sorting has to happen somewhere (it would be nice if it could happen before the first call to exact_change).

```
from copy import copy

def exact_change(target_amount, L):
    L = sorted(L, reverse=True)
    for v in L:
        if v == target_amount:
            return True
        else:
            if v < target_amount:
                L.remove(v)
                return exact_change(target_amount-v, L)
    else:
        return False


print exact_change( 42, [25, 1, 25, 10, 5, 1] )

print exact_change( 42, [25, 1, 25, 10, 5] )
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!

Comment: @Panthera_Tigris, check for completeness before submitting it, I'm not sure if it's correct for all inputs

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form of having exact change is when the `target_amount` is included in the list of coins. One way to recursively reduce the problem to that situation is to iterate over the list of coins, and for each one, subtract it from the `target_amount`, remove it from the available list of coins, and check if the new target amount can be reached by the new list of coins (recursively):

```
def exact_change(target_amount, coins):
    list_len = len(coins)

    if list_len == 0:
        return False

    if target_amount in coins:
        return True

    for i in range(0, list_len):
        reduced = coins[0:i] + coins[i+1:]
        if exact_change(target_amount - coins[i], reduced):
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Nice, you could replace range with xrange, to reduce the number of lists created

Answer (score 0):

```py
def exact_change(target_amount, coins):
    # Write your code here
    usables = [d for d in coins if d<=target_amount]

    if not usables: return False

    if target_amount in usables: return True

    for d in usables:
        if exact_change(target_amount - d, usables):
            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

def exact_match(number, l):
    le = len(l)
    for i in xrange(1, le + 1):
        combs = list(combinations(l, i))
        for comb in combs:
            if sum(comb) == number:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: How could `exact_match(10, [1,5,10])` return `True` then?

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks for clarification. It is very naive approach.

Comment: @mic4ael, I though it must be recursive as well

Comment: That's the problem. It has to be recursive.