# Optimizing specific numbers to reach value

Tags: optimization, divide

I'm trying to make a program, that when given specific values (let's say 1, 4 and 10), will try to get how much of each value is needed to reach a certain amount, say 19.
It will always try to use as many high values as possible, so in this case, the result should be 10*1, 4*2, 1*1.
I tried thinking about it, but couldn't end up with an algorithm that could work...

Any help or hints would be welcome!

Comment: This sounds like a Finding-the-Exact-Change problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431748/exact-change-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a python solution that tries all the choices until one is found. If you pass the values it can use in descending order, the first found will be the one that uses the most high values as possible:

```
def solve(left, idx, nums, used):
        if (left == 0):
            return True
        for i in range(idx, len(nums)):
            j = int(left / nums[idx])
            while (j > 0):
                used.append((nums[idx], j))
                if solve(left - j * nums[idx], idx + 1, nums, used):
                    return True
                used.pop()
                j -= 1
        return False      
solution = []        
solve(19, 0, [10, 4, 1], solution)
print(solution) # will print [(10, 1), (4, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a simple algorithm, one way I found was:

`sort the values, in descending order
keep track on how many values are kept
for each value, do:
    if the sum is equal to the target, stop
    if it isn't the first value, remove one of the previous values
        while the total sum of values is smaller than the objective:
            add the current value once`

Have a nice day!

(As juviant mentionned, this won't work if the skips larger numbers, and only uses smaller ones! I'll try to improve it and post a new version when I get it to work)